# Practice of Letting Users Connect to an Interactive Chat System on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a WIP chat tool with SignalR hub running on my server and would like to add translation feature to it.

So far I set up Azure Translator Text API, Service Bus and Functions. And I've made the SignalR server casts messages to the service bus, then the function triggers upon existing messages on the bus, and posts it to the translator api.

```
Flow of Messages
[Users' Browser] -> [SignalR Hub] -> [Service Bus] -> [Functions] -> [Translator API]
```

Here my concerns are:

1. What is the advantage of using service bus or functions? It is also possible to directly post messages to translator API from my server, but I assume service bus make it easier when I want to scale out my server, is that correct?
2. Related to 1., I know there's Service Bus Relay that enables two systems directly communicate to each other. Is this useful for this kind of project?
3. Where should the messages translated through functions be posted back to? The SignalR hub on my server, or the service bus with some tag that distinguishes whether the message is raw or translated?

Comment: Can you elaborate how the chat and translations expected to work? Is it every message needs to be translated for each person chatting? Only for those that enabled translations? Every message or not? Translation from a single language or not? When translation is available, do you care to show the original to the destinator or not? Thanks.

Comment: There will be some rooms in my chat server, and within the "international rooms" every messages will be translated to every language which the users in the rooms use. Say, if one channel has Japanese, Chinese, U.S. and German users, the messages sent from the Japanese user will be translated to Simplified Chinese, English and German and be sent back to each user. Also, people in the room can know which people post each message and can see the raw text by clicking "see original text" or some manipulation.